# Why does my radeon driver crash when booting?

Tags: 11.04, radeon, acer, aspire

I am trying to install Natty on an Acer Aspire 5810T laptop. Everything works fine once booted, but the laptop will only boot one out of three times. The other times it hangs at a black screen with an error concerning the radeon driver. It is possible however to change to a console using [Crtl]+[Alt]+[F2] but X won't start and the system hangs on an attempt to do a "sudo reboot" and needs to be killed.

Could you take a look at the dmesg output? Maybe you can tell me what is going on.

dmesg on crash: http://pastebin.com/NV83yx3c

dmesg on successful boot: http://pastebin.com/r1q60xKb

Interesting: My Aspire 5810T has two graphic cards, onboard Intel and a Mobility Radeon.
Details:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M92 LP [Mobility Radeon HD 4300 Series]
```

Windows switches between the two depending if the computer is plugged in or on battery, Ubuntu uses only the radeon card.

I already tried:

- Installing the fglrx driver. It doesn't install correctly and I can't use Unity.
- Switching off the Intel card in the BIOS (ATI card can't be switched off), the problem persists.

I'd appreciate any pointers to solve this situation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a workaround. I disabled the Intel card in the BIOS and installed the latest Catalyst driver directly from AMD.
Not a perfect solution, but X starts up fine and unity works.